# The 2nd parameter to `mongoose.model()` should be a schema, but it is a schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to add user to my users collection in MongoDB. I'm using mongoose with NodeJS and Typescript, and when I try to run the project, I get the error:

```
The 2nd parameter to `mongoose.model()` should be a schema or a POJO
at Mongoose.model
```

The error states that the problem is in this file:

```
import { Router, Request, Response } from "express";
const UserType = require("../enums/UserType");
const UserSchema: mongoose.Schema = require("../schemas/UserSchema");
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";


export class UserRouter {
  router: Router;
  private userSchema = mongoose.model("UserSchema", UserSchema, "Users");

  constructor() {
    this.router = Router();
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.router.post("/create", this.createUser);
  }

  //@ts-ignore
  async createUser(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const uid = uuidv4();
    const info = req.body;
    var user = new this.userSchema({
      uid: uid,
      username: info.username,
      password: info.password,
      type: UserType.User,
    });

    console.log(user);
  }
}

const userRouter = new UserRouter();
const router = userRouter.router;

export default router;
```

`UserSchema` is of type `mongoose.Schema<any>`, when hovering on it with the pointer, this is what pops up: `const UserSchema: mongoose.Schema<any>`

This is my UserSchema:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  uid: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  type: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("UserSchema", UserSchema);
```

Why do I keep getting this error message, even though it seems like the error should not be present?

Comment: You exported a model, not a schema in UserSchema file: `module.exports = mongoose.model("UserSchema", UserSchema)`

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc Thanks, so how should I export this? because it does looks like I do gt mongoose.Schema in the UserSchema

Comment: You can change how you require it: `const UserSchema = require("../schemas/UserSchema");` then use that `UserSchema` instead of your `userSchema`

Comment: Rename your UserSchema file to User  then `const User = require("../schemas/User");` may be better because you exported a model, not schema.

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc Thanks, but I have a User class, so I guess that would be confusing. I wrote the User class with the intention to only send back to users a relevant information (not password and createdAt for example), am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you get this error is you declared the mongoose model in a recursive way: `mongoose.model(UserSchema,mongoose.model(),"Users")` in your code. You should export **UserSchema** instead of creating a schema **model** and exporting it. your code should look like this:
`module.exports.UserSchema = UserSchema;` In the other module you could import the schema :
`const {UserSchema} = require("../schemas/UserSchema");` and eventually create a new model of the schema in the UserRouter class:
`private userSchema = mongoose.model("UserSchema", UserSchema);`

It is possible to get the same error if you define `mongoose.model()` twice for the same schema:

Answer (score 1):

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const blogSchema = new Schema

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema // delete new......
```

Comment: Please provide a short description how your answer solves the problem. thank you!

Comment: if you use import and not require, i think type:module is config...


module.exports = mongoose.model("UserSchema", UserSchema);

you need change that by 

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
export default User;

and you can delete 
`const UserSchema= new mongoose.Schema`

and write 

`const userSchema = mongoose.Schema`

Answer (score 0):

Try to check names of exporting files:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

1. *Argument*: **User**
2. *Argument*: User**Schema**